# SQL Count Case NOT COUNT multiple strings

Tags: sql

I am having issues with an assignments for school. I need to seperate the tweets of Donald Trump. I need to get seperate columns. I got the 3 first to work. But the last one where it needs to be neither of the first 3. But keep getting issues.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN software LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Tweets from iPhone',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN software LIKE '%Android%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Tweets from Android',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN software LIKE '%Web Client%' THEN 1 END) AS 'Tweets from Web Client',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN software NOT LIKE ('%Web Client%' OR '%iPhone%' OR '%Android%') THEN 1 END) AS 'Tweets from other Platforms'
FROM tt2
```

Hope I can get some help with this issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT LIKE` doesn't take a list.  You need to use separate conditions:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN software NOT LIKE '%Web Client%' AND software NOT LIKE '%iPhone%' AND software NOT LIKE '%Android%' THEN 1 END) AS TweetsfromotherPlatforms
```

You might be able to use regular expressions for this comparison.  But that depends on your database.

Don't use single quotes for column names -- even if your database allows it.  It is just confusing mixing up identifiers and strings.  Only use single quotes for date and string constants.  The best advice is to name things so no escaping is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is working now and I really appreciate the feedback